# Too many arguments to block call Cordova

Tags: xcode, cordova

I am getting this error when trying to build an archive:
[image]

I updated to the latest version of Cordova. I should mention this is the first time I am trying to build an archive with x-code.

Here is the code:
[image]

I think my issue was an autofix: 
[image]

Comment: Please post your code, full method

Comment: This isn't code I created it's from Cordova

Comment: So please show the path of this snippet

Comment: I added a screenshot of the code

Comment: Tip: you have enough exp. to post code as raw and not image

Comment: Just thought it was quicker, I'll keep it in mind, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead

```
void (^block)(void) = [gPendingSetUserAgentBlocks objectAtIndex:0];
```

Should be:

```
void (^block)() = [gPendingSetUserAgentBlocks objectAtIndex:0];
```

This is a [cordova-ios master](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/blob/master/CordovaLib/Classes/Public/CDVUserAgentUtil.m#L100). This code didn't change since 2016

Comment: Ok, I updated Cordova shouldn't that file update as well or am I missing something?

Comment: @bstras21 have no clue why you got `void` there

Comment: Ok so I added the code you suggested and I think there was an auto fix, I added the image above.

Comment: So I'm assuming don't fix it